# What is the difference between undecidable language and Turing Recognizable language?

Tags: computability, undecidability, semi-decidability

I was wondering what is the difference difference undecidable language and Turing recognizable language. I've seen in some cases where they ask:

1. Prove that the language $ A_{TM} = \{ \ <M,w> | \ M \mbox{ is a Turing Machine accepting } w\}$ is undecidable.
2. Prove that the language $ A_{TM} = \{ \ <M,w> | \ M \mbox{ is a Turing Machine accepting } w\}$ is Turing Recognizable.

Are they the same thing? Can someone elaborate on this issue?

Another one, is the question at hand is known as the halting problem? Or is it different from halting problem?

Comment: Look at the definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A language $L$ is *decidable* if there exists a Turing machine $M$ such that:

- If $x \in L$ and $M$ is run with input $x$, then $M$ halts at an accepting state.
- If $x \notin L$ and $M$ is run with input $x$, then $M$ halts at a rejecting state.

(In particular, $M$ always halts.) If no such Turing machine exists, $L$ is *undecidable*.

A language $L$ is *recognizable* (or, recursively enumerable, abbreviated r.e.) if there exists a Turing machine $M$ such that:

- If $x \in L$ and $M$ is run with input $x$, then $M$ halts.
- If $x \notin L$ and $M$ is run with input $x$, then $M$ doesn't halt.

If no such Turing machine exists, $L$ is *unrecognizable*.

A basic fact about these definitions is:

> A language $L$ is decidable if and only both $L$ and $\overline{L}$ are recognizable.

Your language $A_{TM}$ is one way of stating the halting problem (there are many equivalent ways). It is recognizable but not decidable.

Comment: Is there any subset relation between undecidable language and Turing recognizable language?

Comment: No set is a subset of the other.

Comment: @Robur_131 There is no inclusion between them. However, we have that decidable implies recognizable. (Hence, unrecognizable implies undecidable)

Comment: @YuvalFilmus you wrote If x∉L and M is run with input x, then M doesn't halt. I suppose it should be it may or may not halt. Cause if it does not halt then we would not have recursive languages a subset of recursively enumerable languages would we?

Comment: @SumeetSingh Under your proposed definition, every language is recognizable. Just take the machine that always halts. In order to show that every decidable language is recognizable, you take the Turing machine deciding the language and modify it to recognize the language (exercise).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus This not my definition. Take a look at the 3rd equivalent definition in this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_language

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Its clearly written that may either halt and reject or loop forever when presented with a string not in the language.

Comment: @SumeetSingh You can use this definition if each state is annotated as accepting or rejecting. The Wikipedia definition is equivalent to mine.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus How is that equivalent? You have clearly said does not halt.

Comment: @SumeetSingh A function is r.e. according to my definition iff it is r.e. according to the Wikipedia definition.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Im not saying its wrong. Its incomplete.

Comment: @SumeetSingh It's not incomplete. It is one of many equivalent definitions of recursive enumerability. I'm afraid we'll have to disagree.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I still think that you should write it may halt or it may not. You are a professor for crying out loud.

Comment: @SumeetSingh As I mentioned above, the definition you suggest defines the class of *all* languages rather than just the r.e. ones.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74874/discussion-between-sumeet-singh-and-yuval-filmus).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thats exactly why they are at the top of chomsky hierarchy.